# VS 2010 Professional Trial Version for SP 2010 development?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, visual-studio

Can I use VS 2010 Professional **Trial** Version for SP 2010 portal application Development ?
Currently the customer doesnt have the license of VS 2010 proff.  or ultimate editions.

But because of the existing SP 2010 web portal enhancements/changes, i will be forced to do some coding and debugging and deployments. 
Am looking into this, why should not I use Trial version of these proff or ultimate for few days of development against the SP 2010 environment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, you cant deploy your solution to production. Trail products are only for the internal evaluation.

Here is what it says

**TRIAL USE RIGHTS and CONVERSION for Visual Studio 2010 Professional Trial Edition.**

> If the software is a trial edition, then this Section applies to you.
>   You may install and use any number of copies of the trial software on
>   your devices. You may only use the trial software for internal
>   evaluation purposes. For example, your trial rights do not include the
>   right to deploy or distribute any programs you design or develop with
>   the software for use in a production environment, except that you may
>   deploy your programs internally solely to evaluate the software. You
>   may convert your trial rights at any time to the full rights described
>   in the rest of these license terms by purchasing a commercial license
>   and obtaining a product key from Microsoft or one of its distributors.

You can download the whitepaper [from here](https://www.sjm.com/~/media/galaxy/careers/legal-notices-and-patents/visual%20studio%202010%20professional%20edition%20english.pdf?la=en)